# Substituting a substring with another string for each line of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, lapply, gsub

I have a dataframe and for each row i want to replace a regular parameter in column A with a value in column B.

I can do this with loops, but i cant figure out how i might do this quicker with lapply.

```
column A            column B
hotels in {d}       London
{d} city breaks     Bangkok
cheap hotels {d}    New York
```

I want the result to be:

```
Column A
hotels in London
Bangkok city breaks
cheap hotels New York
```

I can do this with a loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df){
  df$Column A[i] <- gsub("\\{d\\}",df$Column B[i], dfColumn A[i])
}
```

But for millions of rows, this would be slow..

Comment: `lapply` is also a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R approach without loops.
First, read in the data. Note that I have changed the columns' names a bit.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
column.A            column.B
'hotels in {d}'       'London'
'{d} city breaks'     'Bangkok'
'cheap hotels {d}'    'New York'
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- df    # make a copy for results comparison

# your code
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$column.A[i] <- gsub("\\{d\\}",df$column.B[i], df$column.A[i])
}

regmatches(df2$column.A, regexpr("\\{d\\}", df2$column.A)) <- df2$column.B
df2
#               column.A column.B
#1      hotels in London   London
#2   Bangkok city breaks  Bangkok
#3 cheap hotels New York New York


identical(df, df2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: this is nice and appears to be much faster than either of the other two approaches.

Comment: This is awesome thank you! The loop in the desc, across 12 columns and 1.2M rows took about 24hrs to process, even on the R server... this literally takes 5 mins!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in one line with `stringr`, which is vectorised...

```
library(stringr)
df$columnA <- str_replace(df$columnA, "\\{d\\}", df$columnB)

df
                columnA  columnB
1      hotels in London   London
2   Bangkok city breaks  Bangkok
3 cheap hotels New York New York
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with `apply`:

```r
a<-c("{d} rises in the east", "{d} has come")
b <- c("the sun", "morning")

df <- data.frame(a = a, b = b)
df
#>                       a       b
#> 1 {d} rises in the east the sun
#> 2          {d} has come morning

df$a <- apply(df, 1, function(row) {gsub("\\{d\\}", row[2], row[1])})
df
#>                           a       b
#> 1 the sun rises in the east the sun
#> 2          morning has come morning
```